# Do you have any methods for going from CameraRoll to a new view controller?

Tags: ios, image, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to go from Camera Roll to a new view controller. So basically I want to be able to choose a picture and after choosing the picture,  it will be displayed on an imageView on a new view controller? Is that hard to make ?

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:
(NSDictionary *)info{
self.chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
 [self.imageView setImage:self.chosenImage];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Seems pretty basic.  What have you tried...?

Comment: This is what I have right now. I need a bit more clarification for getting to a new view controller after I have exited the cameraroll. Sorry I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 2):

in your image picker delegate methods, whenever you take image it goes in following method

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
  didFinishPickingImage : (UIImage *)image
             editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
 //store image here as NSData or as you like 
 // go to the view controller when you want to use image and use the image data
  // do all the stuf you need in this method
}
```

Comment: Wasim , so from what I'm getting. All of the codes in regards to bringing me to a new view controller should be under the imagePickerController method or so called inside of it right?